# Is it possible to add 3.005 to 4.70 only using int types in C?

Tags: c, floating-point, int

I am asked to input two numbers like 3.005, 3.70 and add, subtract and multiply them without using float or double. Somehow i managed to do something similiar to what i am asked. I input numbers individually.  If i input "3.005" i first input 3, then i input .005. But since 005 doesn't equal to 0.005 i'm having problems. For example i input 3.005 and 4.70 and when i add them i get 7.75, which is not true. How can i fix that? That's how i input my values.

```
printf("first number:");
scanf("%d.%d",&n1.integer,&n1.fraction);
printf("second number:");
scanf("%d.%d",&n2.integer,&n2.fraction);
```

That's my function for adding two values.

```
int add(n1,f1,n2,f2,n1digit,n2digit){ //n1-2digit is number of digits of n1-2's fraction.
int t;
int y=1; 
int fraction;
int integer;
if (n1digit>n2digit){
    t=n1digit;

}
else if (n2digit>n1digit){
    t=n2digit;
}
else { 
    t=n2digit;
}
fraction=f1+f2;
integer=n1+n2;

int temp=fraction;
int i=0; 
while (temp>0){
    temp=temp/10;
    i=i+1;
}
if (i>t){
    integer=integer+1; 
    y=pow(10,i-1);
    fraction=fraction%y;


}
printf("%d.%d\n",integer,fraction);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the hint you have posted to @ruohola's answer, you could do the following:

1. define a maximum number of fractional digits, e.g. 3 or 6
2. read the number as a string, use `strtol()` to convert the integer part. and skip '.'
3. if the fractional part is shorter then the number of fractional digits, append an according number of '0', so '70' becomes '700' or '700000', '5' becomes '500' or '500000'
4. use `strtoul()` to store that number into another (unsigned) integer value

Now you have yout two integer values representing the number an can do the rest

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to impelent this but i'm having problems. When i input 3.005 when max_digit=4, it is converted to 3.0050 within string but when i convert it to integer to make calculations i get "50" as fraction part. So that's causing problems in calculations. I was thinking maybe using binary conversion in this question would work. What do you think?

Comment: 50 as fractional part is ok. E.g. if you wanted to add 1.2 you'd have another fractional value of 2000, an adding both gives you 2050, meaning .2050. if you added 1.999, you'd get 50 + 9990 = 10040 --> .004 (10040 % 10000) and '+1' for the  integer part (10040 / 10000)

Answer (score 3):

Take the input as thousands: enter the numbers as `3005` and `3700`, and in the end divide the result by `1000.0`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was also thinking about implementing something like that but since at my question it is asked to input in xx.xx format, i think that won't work. 

Here is the question: https://i.imgur.com/pzkNSZW.png

What do you think? Since char is also an int type, using it can work?

Comment: Okey, yeah my answer will **not** work for those requirements.

Answer (score 1):

To allow flexibility in the number digits and not require them to be the same, when reading, note the offsets with `"%n"`.

```
int o1, o2
printf("first number:");
// scanf("%d.%d",&n1.integer,&n1.fraction);
scanf("%d.%n%d%n",&n1.integer,&o1, &n1.fraction, &o2);
int n1digit = o2 - o1;
```

Same for `n2`  denominator

Apply the *sign* of the integer part to the fraction part.  OP's code does not do this.

When adding the fractions, form a common power of ten, then add the fractions.

Note: This approach fails with pathological inputs like `"-1. 23", "1.-23", "12."`, etc.